# DataGridViewComboboxColumn for Bound Grid

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am developing a Windows Desktop application in C#.net. I have a `DataGridView` bound to a `DataTable`. I want one of the columns to be edited with `DataGridViewComboBox`.The code is below

```
string query = "SELECT ResultId, LabId, Result, Comments FROM T_Result WHERE LabId = " + labId;
DataTable dtResult = getQueryResult(query);
dgvResult.DataSource = dtResult;
```

Now I want the Result Column to be a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with ComboData from following query

```
DataTable dtComboData = getQueryResult ("SELECT DISTINCT Result FROM T_Result");
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataGridViewComboboxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this approach.  Below is a sample code to add a ComboboxColumn to DataGridView

Ex:-

```
        DataTable dtComboData = getQueryResult("SELECT DISTINCT Result FROM T_Result");
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        col.DataSource = dtComboData;
        col.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;


        dgvResult.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: Do you know how to make this column editable so that user enter any data which is not present in combo item?